# Blob triggered function gets fired twice

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have an azure function that is using BlobTrigger. The function app uses Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions version 1.0.22. I have an Http triggered function that uploads the blob file which in turn will trigger my blob triggered function. Whenever a new blob has been uploaded the function gets triggered twice always. 
I checked the code that uploads blob and it is just uploading one blob always and I tried checking the created and last modified date of blob file inside blob triggered function and both the dates are coming same always.
Can someone please help me getting this issue resolved?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24748200/blobtrigger-triggering-job-multiple-times-in-azure-webjobs-0-3-beta hope this will helps

Comment: Could you post this as an issue in the Azure Functions GitHub so we can better track it and provide the following information: timestamp, Function App version (1.0 or 2.0), Function App name, Function name(s) (as appropriate), invocation IDs of the duplicates, and region? (You can [share your Function App name privately.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately))